# Saving instances on openstack

Tags: openstack

I have installed openstack by installing devstack environment, where I am finding difficult to save the work after host reboot.However if I install openstack component wise, will it help me in any ways in saving my work after host reboot, and are there any extra  benefits of installing openstack component wise

Answer (score 2):

Installing Openstack component wise would certainly enhance your end to end understanding of how services interact with each other. Devstack is an all in one place sort of installation. For better understanding, I'd recommend to install each component manually following the Openstack documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The cause why the vm data is lost after reboot is because you are launched the vm with the ephemeral disk, which will be gone after the vm reboot.

Try to create the instance with root disk, then you will have the permenant disk.